# How can I create a list of reserved words in a Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, reserved-words

I know that I can just browse the web for these words but is there a way to just let Ruby do it for me? You don't have to give me a whole program, just some hints to let me go about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can always take a look at the ruby's source code: [keywords](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/defs/keywords).

Answer (score 2):

You can't get Ruby to do this for you.

However, here's the list from Dave Thomas's *Programming Ruby 1.9, The Pragmatic Programmers' Guide* (Also known as the Pickaxe):

> `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, BEGIN, END, alias, and, begin, break, case, class, def, defined?, do, else, elsif, end, ensure, false, for, if, in module, next, nil, not, or, redo, rescue, retry, return, self, super, then, true, undef, unless, until, when, while, yield

Comment: Here's the page it's on http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html under Names.